# Is it possible to skip the version of a maven parent in the child?

Tags: maven

In the [Sonatype Maven Guide](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/optimizing-sect-final-poms.html) the example multi-module project must define the version of the project in the parent `pom.xml` and in all the child `pom.xml`s (to refer to the version of the parent).

Is there a way to define the version in a single location? It seems like an awfully lot of changes need to be made to bump the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the correct way to organize a multi-module Maven project is to have one project to keep track of artifact versions by means of its `dependencyManagement` section, which is the parent of all other projects; and an *aggregator* project which contains all the other projects as `modules`, parent included.

This allows you to centralize version handling for dependencies both between your projects and towards external libraries. You still have to explicitly keep track of the correspondence between each project's version in its pom and in the parent project, as well as the correspondence between the parent's version in its pom and in all its descendents.

I agree that it's a lot of work, and it's very easy to make mistakes: consider automating it with custom plugins and/or scripts. The [Maven Release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) could be of help on this problem.

Comment: what is the advantage of having a parent plus aggregator over having just a parent that does the aggregation?

Comment: It is a better separation of concerns. Having dependency management separate from aggregation makes it easier to reuse specific projects in different contexts, should the need arise. Moreover, depending on which version control tool you use, you might be able to have different aggregators that combine overlapping subsets of sub-projects, for instance to turn a single product in a product family.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as essentially "No, it is not possible to... and here is some extra relevant information"